# Given the inverses of two Toeplitz matrices is there a way to get the first row of the inverse of their sum without doing another inverse

Tags: toeplitz-matrices

I have a calculation that requires the inverse of the weighted sum of two Toeplitz matrices aT1 + bT2 for many different weights a,b.
Inverting T1, T2 or aT1+bT2 is an O(n^2)  operation using Levinson/Trench.
I have to repeat that for each a,b and that is the dominant effort in my problem. So I would like to find a way of inverting T1 and T2 separately once and for all and then somehow with less than O(n^2) effort get the first row of the inverse of aT1 +bT2 for each a,b

Comment: Given the form of your data I suspect that you might be able to recast it as an FFT-type problem and at least get your time down to O(n log n) relatively straightforwardly.

Comment: I looked at the superfast algorithms but they're not all they're cracked up to be.  O(n log n) turned out to be  more like O(6n log 2n)

Comment: IFF  the Toeplitz matrices T1  and T2 were cyclic shift matrices it would be easier because both would be diagonalized by the same DFT  matrix i.e  T1 = W(d2) W# and T2 = W(d2)W# so aT1+bT2  inverse is just